Stuck at Minimal Bash Like Line editing, How to get the Grub selection menu back
I have an nvme ssd where I have all my systems triple booted windows kali and arch.
I had a hardware problem in the computer keyboard and while repairing I had to remove the nvme and place it back.
When I booted it went directly to Windows instead of the usual grub menu. When I tried to change the bios settings I found only two options windows or ubuntu something when choosing ubuntu it gives me the minimal bash like line editing I tried following some solutions to boot from it but when I use the ls command with the disk partitions containing the systems it says unknown file system.
Any help is appreciated.

UEFI forgets entries, except Windows when a drive is unplugged. You can use efibootmgr to recreate entry or reinstall grub. https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface#Important_UEFI_Shell_Commands  See also man efibootmgr

Probably the easiest and most reliable way to do that is to reinstall GRUB. You can install Arch Linux to a USB flash drive, boot into it, and then use the CLI to reconfigure GRUB.
